# Can't change owner of file when I am the owner

Tags: linux

I am the owner of the file (userA), and I can't change it to userB.

when I run `chown -R userB ./`

It tells me : `failed to change ownership of`
what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allowed to do that, it's just how permissions work. Imagine the implications of being able to chown anything arbitrarily on a system with user disk quotas enforced. It would be trivial to push somebody over their quota.

Comment: How to resolve it?

Comment: If you are only a user on the box, ask your admin and if you have root rights, use `sudo chown`.

Comment: It may be worth talking about why you cannot do it.

Comment: The other reason for not being able to do this is easily seen: consider your little binary that adds an extra line to `/etc/passwd`; you own it, since you compiled it, then you `chmod 4755 ./binary ; chown root:root ./binary ; ./binary`.  Hey presto, no system security.  The ability to give a file away by chown is inconsistent with the sudo bit, unless you want no system security at all.

Comment: @MadHatter: Great addition, I didn't even think about that.

Comment: It's worth asking this too: what are you trying to effectively accomplish by giving the file to someone? There may be other options to do what you're trying to accomplish.